# extra database is being added to the Android File Explorer

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an existing DB that I have been able to copy to my File Explorer, went on Youtube and tweeked the code, but I am getting 3 databases. under the /data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases I get the following:

ab.sqlite - this is the one I want
ab.sqlite-journal - I assume this is an Android file that needs to be created

now under /data/data/com.xxx.xxx I get the following:

**databasesab.sqlite - where from is this coming?**

here is the DataBaseHelper Code:

```
`private static final String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases";
    private static final String DB_NAME ="ab.sqlite";
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1;

//inserting Table names and column names

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "abc";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_1 = "Voltage";


public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

private final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void createDatabase() {
    createDB();
}
private void createDB() {
    boolean dbExist = DBExists();

    if (!dbExist) {

        //Method we creates an empty database to default system location
        //Overwrite the database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        //Copy the database we included
        copyDBFromResource();
    }   
}

    private boolean DBExists() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;

        try {
            String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setLocale (Locale.getDefault());
            db.setVersion(1);

        }catch (SQLiteException e) {

            Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found");

        }
        if (db != null) {

            db.close();

        }

        return db !=null ? true : false;

}
    private void copyDBFromResource() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        String dbFilePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        try {

            inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

            byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error ("Problem copying database from resource file.");

        }

        }   
}
`
```

any help will be appreciated because I really can't seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is here:

```
private static final String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases";
private static final String DB_NAME ="ab.sqlite";
```

and here:

```
String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
```

you are missing the slash after databases.

Comment: Eclipse is recommending not to hard code the DB_PATH it is telling me to do the following:

Context.getFilesDir().getPath

what is the opion of this formum

Comment: sorry one last thing...what tis the ab.sqlite-journal file

Comment: Eclipse is right that you shouldn't define your DB path.. I usually do this: String databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
String dbFilePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
```

that is why your are getting databasesab.sqlite,databases + ab

Comment: Thank you very much.  Something as simple as a / makes a world of difference.